# SQL not properly ended?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know i don't have to use SQL but i have other code between declare begin and end . I just extracted this part and everything works except this . I get the following error:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

This is the code:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
    UPDATE octombrie
    SET nr_imprumut = I.nr
    from (select book_date bd,count(book_date) nr  
              from rental
             where to_char(book_date,'mm') like '10'
           group by book_date) I
    where data = I.bd;
END;
/
```

I don't get it what did i do wrong ?

EDIT: book_date will give me a day from the month of october. In that day multiple books are rented, so i find out how many books i rented by counting the number of times the same date apears (the rented books are in the rental table). I then take this data and Update  October table(i put the number of books aka 'nr' where the date in the october table matches the date in which the books where rented);

Comment: because the days already exist in octombrie but the number of rented books is 0 , so i update those columns my bad for saying insert instead of update

Comment: `from` is not legal in an `update` statement. Please check the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708

Comment: oh thought so but then i saw a guy with from and i was like , wow nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
    UPDATE octombrie o
       SET o.nr_imprumut = 
           (select count(r.book_date)
             from rental r 
            where to_char(r.book_date,'mm') like '10' and o.data = r.book_date)
    WHERE exists (select 1 from rental r 
                   where to_char(r.book_date,'mm') like '10' and o.data = r.book_date);
END;
```

Use

```
where exists (select 1 from rental r 
              where to_char(r.book_date,'mm') like '10' and o.data = r.book_date)
```

if you want to update only those rows for which you found something in rental (otherwise ALL rows will be updated in octombrie)

Another variant (updates all October 2014 data in octombrie; for each data calculates the number of rental ON this data)

```
UPDATE octombrie o
SET o.nr_imprumut = 
    (select count(r.book_date)
      from rental r 
     where r.book_date between trunc(o.data) and trunc(o.data) + 1 - 1/24/60/60)
WHERE o.data between to_date('2014-10-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2014-10-31 23:59:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

Comment: your answer is good, i mean it compiles but it has some problems . First i need the count for each day not a total count so i need that group by book_date and . Second (well it's not a problem) i do not not need Where Exists because from rental i only get dates in which something was rented

Comment: after i put what i need in place (select count(r.book_date),r.book_date
       from rental r,octombrie o
      where to_char(r.book_date,'mm') like '10'
        and to_char(o.data,'dd-mm') like to_char(r.book_date,'dd-mm')
      GROUP BY r.book_date
  ) THE SAME ERROR is there .....

Comment: @LucianTarna  You are wrong, I guess you don't know how subqueries work (no offence meant). You don't need a `group by` because the subquery is executed separately for each row affected by the `update` statement. Without the `where exists`, the `update` statement will update all other rows (not in october) to 0, I don't think you want that.

Comment: @Lucian Tarna I updated the answer. But I don't understand why you use condition for October? You need to update only October data?

Comment: the offence taken obviously :P. But if i run your statement after i compare the data like this : to_char(o.data,'dd-mm') like to_char(r.book_date,'dd-mm') because otherwise i get a 0 , i get 8 which is the total number of books rented in october , i need to get something like : on 1st OCT : 1, on 2nd OCT : 2 and on 3rd OCT: 5

Comment: all your answers are perfect but they give me the total on the whole month , i need the total on each day of october :))

Comment: @Lucian Tarna No, it's not true. Have you looked the last query?

Comment: yes i've looked at all , all of them produce me the answer 8 , which is the total for October month

Comment: @Multisync it's ok i did it finally , thank you :D for the help and interest! You were actually right i was doing the query wrong(when i took it out of the UPDATE statement) and wasn't actually thinking of that you wrote there i am very sorry !

Answer (score 1):

I guess you really wanted to something like that:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
    UPDATE octombrie o
      SET o.nr_imprumut = 
        (SELECT count(1)
           FROM rental r 
           WHERE r.book_date between o.data and o.data+1-1/86400)
      WHERE data between to_date('2014-10-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2014-10-31','yyyy-mm-dd');
END;
```

Note that the WHERE-clause of the UPDATE-statement specifies a year, I don't think you want to updated your records for all days in any october. Limiting the date like that (with a BETWEEN operator, but without a TO_CHAR) makes it possible to use an index on octombrie.data, something I hope you have.

Comment: it works but it produces me the result '8' which is the total number of rented books in october month, i need the total in each day of october month(so on the 1st i have rented 2 books , on the 2nd i have rented 3 books and so on)

Comment: Thank you , your answer is perfect! :D  i take everything i said back i am retarded

Comment: No you are not ;-) But you need to learn, like we all had to.